# Data not appending to element in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
  <script id ="ajaxTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each}}
    <li>
        <span class="meta">{{name}} on {{date}}</span>
        <p>{{comment}}</p>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  </ul>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //document.write("Hello");
        var data = [{
          "name":"Name2",
          "date":"12/12/1999"
        }, {
          "name":"Name1",
          "date":"12/12/1999"        
        }]
        var source = $.trim($('#ajaxTemplate').html());
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(data);
      //document.write(html);
        $('ul').append(html);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in the above code. I am not able to append the compiled JS code to DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below one works perfectly, see my change to the code. `{{#each data}}` references `data.data` and expects it to be an `array` to loop through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
  <script id ="ajaxTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each data}}
    <li>
        <span class="meta">{{this.name}} on {{this.date}}</span>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  </ul>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //document.write("Hello");
        var data = {data:[{
          "name":"Vinoth",
          "date":"12/12/1984"
           }, {
          "name":"Kevin",
          "date":"7/23/1984"        
        }]};
        var source = $.trim($('#ajaxTemplate').html());
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(data);
        //document.write(html);
        $('ul').append(html);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Working example**: 
http://jsbin.com/ecazege/1

Also you can use `{{#each this}}` and then you don't need to alter the data at all on what i did. using `this` is more readable way.

Below fiddle using `this`.
http://jsbin.com/ecazege/6

Answer (score 1):

`{{#each}}` can not be used without parameter.

You can use the tip `{{#each .}}` or simply wrap your array in an object like this

```
 <script id ="ajaxTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each items}}
    <li>
        <span class="meta">{{name}} on {{date}}</span>
        <p>{{comment}}</p>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  </ul>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //document.write("Hello");
        var data = [{
          "name":"Name2",
          "date":"12/12/1999"
        }, {
          "name":"Name1",
          "date":"12/12/1999"        
        }]
        var source = $.trim($('#ajaxTemplate').html());
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template({items});
      //document.write(html);
        $('ul').append(html);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the item to be iterated over when calling each. In this case, you would be using `{{#each data}}`